# Using JUCE ::paint on iOS

Tags: ios, juce

I have some code using JUCE which renders graphics in an overridden `:paint(Graphics& g)` function.

How can I integrate this on iOS so that it draws on screen?

Can it be connected to a GLKitView? Is that even needed?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything extra, it'll paint just fine on iOS.

The whole point of JUCE is so that you can write your code once and have it run cross-platform. That said, if you really need to do something native then you can use functions like [`getWindowHandle()`](https://www.juce.com/doc/classComponent#a0d340d822e9a91fc665d73bbe1e91d72) to get down into those kind of details.

For iOS, [`getWindowHandle()`](https://www.juce.com/doc/classComponent#a0d340d822e9a91fc665d73bbe1e91d72) appears to return a [`UIView*`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/). This will change for other platforms.

Comment: I dont see how I should attach it to a UIView so it can be drawn. Im using UIKit for the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the link but could you explain how this connects to iOS? What kind of view is used? A GLKView? How is the code inside the paint function linked to this view? Or should I just copy the code and place it in the GLKView draw function?

Comment: I appreciate the time on this :) but its still fragmented. I dont know what the connection is. So I have a window handle, what now? :D

Comment: Sounds like a bit of an XY problem :) Please update your question for something more specific. If you could provide an small example of what you're trying to achieve that might help. Like I hinted at in the answer, if you just want a cross platform GUI then just use the JUCE classes in your `paint` member function and you're done on all platforms! :)